# C++ Segmentation fault vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault but I'm not sure where

The error produced in gdb states:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100003c03 in std::__1::vector<tile, std::__1::allocator<tile> >::operator[] (this=0x0, __n=0)
at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1497
1497        return this->__begin_[__n];
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000100003c03 in std::__1::vector<tile, std::__1::allocator<tile> >::operator[] (this=0x0, __n=0)
at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1497
#1  g2048::resume (this=0x7fff5fbff990) at ./game.hpp:430
```

And here is the part of the code where the problem is, I suppose:

```
std::vector<std::vector<tile> > board;

vector<int> readIntoVector() {
    char c;
    int temp;
    bool nonum;
    vector<int> v;

    ifstream in("save_game.txt", ios::in);

    if (!in.is_open()) cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    nonum = false;
    in >> sscore;

    while(in.good()) {
        in >> c;

        if (isdigit(c)) { //if the input is a number
            nonum = false;
            in.putback(c);
            in >> temp;
            v.push_back(temp);
        }
        else if (c == '|') { //if input is |
            in >> c;
            in.putback(c);
            if (isdigit(c)) nonum = false; //if next character is a number, don't add a 0
            else nonum = true; //if is not a number, add a zero
        }
        else if (c == '#') { //Case for 0 in the first position of the grid in each line
            in >> c;
            in.putback(c);
            if (c == '|') //if next character is |, means there's no number, so add 0
                nonum = true;
            else nonum = false;
        }
        else nonum = false;

        if (nonum)
            v.push_back(0); //add 0 in the vector
    }

    in.close();

    return v;
}

void resume() {
    cout << "In resume" << endl;
    vector<int> v = readIntoVector();
    cout << "Printing normal vector: ";
    Print(v);
    std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Printing reverse vector: ";
    Print(v);
    for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
            board[x][y].val = (uint) v.back();
            v.pop_back();
        }
    score = sscore;
}
```

And tile.hpp

```
//Class tile
class tile {

public:
    tile() : val( 0 ), blocked( false ) {}
    uint val;
    bool blocked;
};
```

I don't know is the error in the code, maybe I try to assign an empty vector, but the file read by the vector always contains something.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where in your code does the exception happen?  If you are unsure you should use the debugger to walk through the code to find it or use cout statements so you know where in the code you are.

Comment: vector should be preallocated for some amount of data

Comment: You should get more familiar with your debugger. It's way more powerful than just telling you the line in some library where your code actually crashed.

Comment: The debugger says the error is in board[x][y].val = (uint) v.back();

Comment: Where do you add anything to `board`?

Comment: I can't copy the complete code here, but I'm completely sure that I'm adding

Comment: You ran your program under Valgrind before posting here, I hope?  What did it tell you about the problematic access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize `v`. Also, where do you initialize `board`? Thirdly, how can you ensure `v` contains as many items as `board`?

Comment: The code is much more bigger, but I can't paste it. I'm going to initialize v and then I will try it again. Thank you.

Comment: That's it, thank you for your help :)